# Facebook Graph API: /me/friends not empty

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

As far as I know /me/friends request in Graph API v2.1 returns only those users, who use my app.

But when I call it I get brief information about one of my friends who does not use my app and did not grant any permissions to it.

Why does this happens? May be there are some specific profile settings?

Comment: You are sure you are using API v2.1?

Comment: @WizKid yes, I am. I have only one entry in data set and 36 friends, and my app is still on development stage

Comment: Then I suggest that you file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs if you are sure that your friends haven't logged into your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is test you can do to see if this a bug or not.

1. Make a API call to `DELETE /user-id/permissions` using your App `access_token` to remove the friend from the app (replace `user-id` with your friends ID). The API will return `true` if the user was removed successfully (you'll get this even if they didn't authorise the app).
2. Then try to access the friends list again and see if the user is there.
3. If the user is still there, it's definitely a bug with the API. If the user is no longer there, it means at some point the user did authorise the app.

See the relevant documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/permissions/), under `Deleting`.